# how to establish the point "." as a thousand separator in the numbers of the Y axis in R?

Tags: r

I'm using the plot function and I would like my numbers to have a thousand separator on the Y axis. For example, in the case of 1000 I would like the 1,000 number to be seen on the axis, or in the case of 10000, for example, on the 10,000 axis .

Comment: ggplot or base plot? Or something else? Can you make a small example? even just `plot(1000, 10000)` if that is comparable to your actual use.

Comment: I'm using the plot function

Comment: `plot()` is a generic function so it can do very different things based on what you pass to it. It's always better to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) when asking for help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using base `plot()` you can turn off the default axes, then just use `axis()` to draw whatever you like on the axes

```
x<-seq(0, 100000, length.out=11)
y<-seq(0, 10000, length.out=11)
plot(x,y, xaxt="n", yaxt="n")

axis(1, axTicks(1), format(axTicks(1), big.mark = "."))
axis(2, axTicks(2), format(axTicks(2), big.mark = "."))
```

Comment: Sorry for unnecessary edits, I got confused between the questions title and text.

Comment: I have a small problem everything works fine, but for some reason the number changes thickness

Comment: Agreed, but the title seems *very clear* about the point ".", so I decided your way was probably right. (And it's pretty clear how to change it anyway.)

Comment: @RogerFigueroaQuintero Did you use `xaxt="n", yaxt="n"` in the `plot()` to turn off the default axes as I did above?

Comment: Yes, I had forgotten "xaxt =" n ", yaxt =" n. "Thank you very much